# How to set title for iOS push notification using pushd?

Tags: ios, push-notification, pushd

In Apple iOS documentation it is mentioned that:

> **alert** 
>   string/dictionary
>
> If this property is included, the system displays a standard alert or a banner, based on the user’s setting.
>   You can specify a string or a dictionary as the value of alert. If you specify a string, it becomes the message text of an alert with two buttons: Close and View. If the user taps View, the app launches. If you specify a dictionary, refer to Table 5-2 for descriptions of the keys of this dictionary.
>
> **title** 
>   string
>
> A short string describing the purpose of the notification. Apple Watch displays this string as part of the notification interface. This string is displayed only briefly and should be crafted so that it can be understood quickly. This key was added in iOS 8.2.
>
> **body**
>   string
>
> The text of the alert message.

Now I want to set title for the push notification to be shown on iOS, I have sent the below payload:

```
{'data.project': {'ack': 0,
              'c': {'id': 'SOME DATA'},
              'ca': 1,
              't': 'e/user',
              'v': '1',
              'vm': 2},
 'msg': 'My message',
 'title': 'My custom title'}
```

The push is sent but no title is set on the mobile device. Does `pushd` support it? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use this JSON Payload for sending push notification from backend. Hope this will help you. Here, **"title"** is the title of push notification and **"body"** is the text of alert message.

```
{
     "registration_ids" : ["put_id_here"],
    "notification" : {
        "content_available" : true,
        "body" : "this is body",
        "title" : "this is title",
        "sound" : "default",
        "badge" : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `registration_ids `, as I do not use that in my payload and send push?

Comment: "registration_ids" is an array of the registration tokens acquired by calling FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() on a device. If you put multiple registration tokens in the array, the same push notification will be sent to each.

Comment: I got error of `error: Invalid payload Error: Invalid field: body` and then added body to `payloadFilter: ['body']`, but got the error again after restart.